# RequireJS module that extends another module

Tags: requirejs, amd

I'm using a project that has 2 different files wrapped in AMD which one extends the other, project is [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch).

The project has 2 files (`build/bundle.js` and `build/formatters.js`) each export `jsondiffpatch`.  When I include them in my file like:

```
define(['jsondiffpatch',
        'jsondiffpatch-formatters'], function (jsondiffpatch) {
});
```

the formatters extensions are not present.  If I change the main config make `jsondiffpath` depend on the formatters like:

```
shim: {
    'jsondiffpatch': {
        deps: ['jsondiffpatch-formatters']
    }
}
```

I still don't get the formatters.  This is a pretty common practice, but haven't seen to overcome it; i know its something simple, what am i missing?

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/build/formatters.js and 
https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/build/bundle.js but these don't look like AMD files to me.

Also, shouldn't your code be:
define(['jsondiffpatch',
        'jsondiffpatch-formatters'], function (jsondiffpatch, formatters) {
});

Comment: If I do that `formatters` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
shim: {
    'jsondiffpatch-formatters': {
        deps: ['jsondiffpatch'],
        exports: 'jsondiffpatch.formatters'
    },
    'jsondiffpatch': {
        exports: 'jsondiffpatch'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load jsondiffpatch with an AMD loader like RequireJS the formatters are a *different module*. In other words, it works slightly differently from when you load jsondiffpatch without an AMD-loader. Here's a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jsondiffpatch/src/formatters/html.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jsondiffpatch/src/formatters/annotated.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visual"></div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="annotated"></div>
    <script>
      require.config({
        baseUrl: ".",
        paths: {
          jsondiffpatch: "bower_components/jsondiffpatch/build/bundle",
          "jsondiffpatch.formatters": "bower_components/jsondiffpatch/build/formatters"
        },
        enforceDefine: true
      });
      require(["jsondiffpatch", "jsondiffpatch.formatters"],
        function (jsdp, formatters) {

        //
        // Code here adapted from jsondiffpatch's examples:
        // https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch
        //
        var left = { a: 3, b: 4 };
        var right = { a: 5, c: 9 };
        var delta = jsdp.diff(left, right);

        document.getElementById('visual').innerHTML =
          formatters.html.format(delta, left);
        document.getElementById('annotated').innerHTML =
          formatters.annotated.format(delta, left);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only thing you need other than this HTML above is to install RequireJS and jsondiffpatch with Bower.